# must be real number, not TensorVariable

Tags: python, math, pymc, exp

My code is:

```py
h = pm.Normal("h", mu=0.0, sigma=0.1)
a = pm.Normal("a", mu=mu_a, sigma=tau_a, dims="h")
d = pm.Normal("d", mu=mu_d, sigma=tau_d, dims="a") 
theta_1 = math.exp(h + a + d)
```

```
error:
---> 14 theta_1 = math.exp(a + d)

TypeError: must be real number, not TensorVariable
```

Comment: what is pm and what are you trying to do with the code please explain more about the problem and if you give an expected answer it will be appreciated

Comment: pm means pymc3.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Unforunately python's builtin `math` library doesn't support `theano` tensors. So you need to follow https://discourse.pymc.io/t/error-in-basic-model-due-to-trigonometric-functions-using-math-library/2825/2 in using `pymc3.math....` or `theano.tensor` (for example).

I am having the same problem in needing to pymc3-ize a custom function.

HTH